# Fail to run EXE file on Azure Webapp

Tags: python, node.js, azure

I am trying to run an exe file on [Azure Webapp](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) from nodejs server. The exe is created from a simple python file by [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
let cmd = 'hello.exe';
let child = exec(
    cmd, {
        cwd: path_to_exe_file
    },
    function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error === null) {
            res.render('index', { title: stdout });
        } else {
            console.log(error);                
            res.json({
                'status': '400',
                'res': error
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Everything works well on my machine but when I deploy to Azure webapp it turns out an error: **The application has failed to start 
because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect**

```
Error: Command failed: hello.exe The application has failed to start 
because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. 
Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe
tool for more detail. 
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12) 
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) 
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) 
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16) 
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5) killed: false, code: 1, signal: null, cmd: 'hello.exe' }
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: By defauly, Azure Web App contains python runtime, you can still exec python script in node.js script on Azure Web Apps. And the issue should due to any C++ dependencies `pyinstaller` used.  As we have few permission to handle C++ components on Azure Web App. So, if it is possible, can you try to exec python scripts directly?

Comment: Yes, the problem due to pyinstaller. How about .Net exe file, can I run .Net exe file in nodejs script on Azure Web Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, the problem due to pyinstaller. How about .Net exe file, can I run .Net exe file in nodejs script on Azure Web Apps?

Yes, basically we can. And also it works in my test project with the simpliest .NET console exe.

But there are some points we need to pay attention on, the Azure Web App env as a sanbox, there are several strict restrictions and limitations that not all the .NET exe application can be executed on Azure Web Apps. for more details, you can refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox.

Additionally, depends on your scenario, you can try to consider use [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) to run some exe applications or tasks.